# Python: format in xlsxwriter based on True/False Pandas Serie

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, xlsxwriter

I have a Panda series named `Mask_True` populated with True or False.

[image]

I'm also creating and Excel file by using xlsxwriter.
I want to format the cells of column A, row by row, depending on True/False value in the corresponding value of the Mask.
I'd like not to add additional columns in Excel.
Below is the code I am working around:

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE','font_color': '#9C0006'})
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A100', {'type': 'formula',.
criteria': '='+str(MASK_TRUE[+'ROW($A1)'+])+'='+str('False')+'',
'format':   format1})
```

Comment: Is the True/False column actual boolean values or strings? From the default positioning they look like strings.

Comment: They are boolean value